# How to restore python on OS X Yosemite after I've deleted something?

Tags: python, terminal

I think I previously installed python through homebrew. It was not a good idea but I did:

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
$ sudo rm -R /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

.. and then the terminal told me...

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

But when I run python again

```
$ python
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

So I did this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Now python does run on my terminal but I was wondering if it would be better to put something back where I deleted it, and how I could "restore" however python was before I messed with it?

Thanks!

Comment: why did you remove python? what were you attempting to do?

Comment: Which version have you installed through homebrew? Can you execute something with `python3` ? Type `python3` in your terminal, are you forwarded to the interactive python3 interpreter?

Comment: ok, so you are at least able to run python if you need it. But I'd say you should follow the instructions @abarnert posted below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've got a multitude of problems here.

Let's start off with this:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python/2.7` is neither the Apple Python nor the Homebrew Python. You apparently installed a *third* Python, maybe the one from the official python.org binary installers. Removing that one won't affect the Homebrew one.

`/usr/local/bin/python` is not the Apple Python either. It may be a symlink to your third Python or to the Homebrew Python, but it's not from Apple.

Here's where each Python goes:

- Apple's Python is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python/2.7`. It also includes various wrapper executables in `/usr/bin`, including `/usr/bin/python`, that point at the `/System` framework. Any extra stuff you install with that Python (e.g., via `easy_install` or `pip`) that includes executables or scripts will go into `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`, but Apple's pre-installed stuff never does.
- Most third-party binary installers install into `/Library/Frameworks/Python/2.7`. Different versions can optionally add the framework's `bin` directory to your path, or symlink the binaries into `/usr/local/bin`.
- Homebrew installs to somewhere like `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8`, then symlinks various executables and scripts into `/usr/local/bin`.

So, the fact that you're trying to get back to the Apple Python by making sure `/usr/local/bin` is on your PATH is already heading in the wrong direction.

---

Meanwhile, never manually delete something installed by Homebrew unless `brew doctor` tells you to. Just use `brew uninstall python`—or, if you want to move it out of the way temporarily, with the option of restoring it later, `brew unlink python`.

---

Finally, even after changing your `PATH`, the shell may have cached the best location to find `python`, so either read up on the `hash` command or, if you don't want to learn more about bash, just make sure to open a new shell (e.g., by opening a new tab in Terminal.app).

---

Anyway, how do you get back to where you were?

You need to cleanly uninstall *both* extra Pythons. I already explained how to do that with the Homebrew one above. For the third one, you've done most of it, but there are apparently things left behind in `/usr/local/bin`. If they're all dangling symlinks, as seems most likely, you can find them pretty easily with, e.g., `ls -l /usr/local/bin |grep /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework |grep -v /System`.

Having done that, just fire up a new shell, and `which python` should tell you `/usr/bin/python`, and everything will be happy again.

Comment: So, what someone _did_ delete the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python` directory and wanted to get the `Quartz` stuff back?  I'm asking for a, ummm, friend.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the detailed answer. That helped a different situation than, but your description was accurate to the point and worked like a charm!

Comment: @DuckPuncher I realize this is a bit late to help you(r friend), but the 5 upvotes imply you’re not the only one (as does the fact that I once did this...). Running OS X repair should work. Try that first. If not, upgrading OS X (e.g., 10.10 to 10.11) should, but that part probably doesn’t help. Worst-case scenario: do a clean install on the same system (or a close-enough one) to a temporary empty partition or disk, then reboot to your normal OS X and copy stuff over from the new partition’s System to the old one. This isn’t totally safe in general, but it’s safe enough here.

Comment: @DuckPuncher If you’re willing to live dangerously, if you have a friend with a similar Mac with the same major version of OS X, the Pythons are _probably_ identical. Try comparing a bunch of the stuff you didn’t delete (like the executable itself), and if they’re all the same, the Quartz libs probably were too, so copy them and cross your fingers. Fortunately, Apple doesn’t upgrade their Python very often, and I don’t think they do any per-machine code signing on it, so as long as the gods of undocumented partly-closed-source Unix are on your side, you’ll be fine.