# Django Rest framework - If table contains data in response showing Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.10

I am using DjangoRestFramework for rest api

**In get request**
If there is no data in table the response is showing empty.
If there is data in table the response is showing empty Server Error (500).

The follwoing is my code

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from firstexample.models import Employee

class employeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'address')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets
from firstexample.models import Employee
from firstexample.serializers import employeeSerializer
# Create your views here.


class employeeList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        employees = Employee.objects.all()
        serializer = employeeSerializer(employees, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = employeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from firstexample import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^employeesList/$', views.employeeList.as_view()),
]
```

Can any one please help me out. I spent more time on this but i didnot figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Error code**

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 05, 2015 - 07:50:03
Django version 1.10.dev20151112003354, using settings 'helloworld.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QuerySet [<Employee: Employee object>]>
Internal Server Error: /employeesList/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/Python/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/Python/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/Python/django/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/Python/django/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/pythonlearning/helloworld/firstexample/views.py", line 17, in get
    print(serializer.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 674, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 239, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 614, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 459, in to_representation
    fields = self._readable_fields
  File "/Users/jaikakkar/Desktop/Python/django/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 353, in _readable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 339, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 918, in get_fields
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 69, in get_field_info
    reverse_relations = _get_reverse_relationships(opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 137, in _get_reverse_relationships
    for relation in opts.get_all_related_objects():
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects'
[05/Dec/2015 07:50:04] "GET /employeesList/ HTTP/1.1" 500 114115
```

Comment: why are you using `format=None` whilst using a serializer? Try removing `format=None` from your `get` and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Removed format=None but still getting same error.

Comment: What's in console stack trace? Set debug=True in config and show us the details

Comment: added error code in question please check once

Comment: What's the version of drf you are using?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Drf version 3.3.1

Comment: And django 1.1? Can you update to recent version?

Comment: Drf needs django 1.7+

Comment: Ok I am checking right now and will let you know

Comment: If you're using an outdated version of django that would definitely explain why drf is trying to access non-existent attributes.

Comment: Your other potential problem is location of libraries - DRF sits in /Library and Django is located in /Desktop/Python/... (mixture of installs done with sudo in the first case). I suggest you take care of this at some point - stick with brew/pip and never install with sudo. Here is a good one on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917765/how-to-restore-python-on-os-x-yosemite-after-ive-deleted-something

Comment: @ChathanDriehuys, I am sure he is: "Django version 1.10.dev20151112003354" in the stacktrace above.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula, python / import django / django.VERSION will tell you for sure.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am using 1.10.dev version

Comment: I created vertual environment with django1.9 and drf3.3.1 now the request and response working perfect thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRF version 3+ does not work with Django 1.1 (that's on your stacktrace above), it requires Django 1.7+. Upgrade to recent version of Django and remove `format=None` from the `.get()` method in your view.

Comment: I created vertual environment with django1.9 and drf3.3.1 now the request and response working perfect thank you very much  for your help. I think the problem is also because of Drf sits in /Library and Django located in /desktop/Python which you mentioned in comment.